# How can I get callback when ListView Item appear or disappear?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter, flutter-layout

On iOS, there are delegate methods for TableView or CollectionView, like `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)`, is there equivalent callback for flutter ListView item?